# How do I refresh hibernate object after changes made by stored procedure

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, stored-procedures, grails-orm

In my grails application, we are calling a stored procedure that may update several thousands of records. After the stored-proc call, I need to send many of these records back to the UI in json format. But, hibernate continues to see the old object after the stored proc is complete. I have tried evict() on each of those objects and loaded those again using HQL, but no avail.

What is the best way out of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Answer lies in the question. :) Use `refresh()`. Refer [this](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/refresh.html).

If you want to clear the hibernate session altogether then you can use `session.clear()`. Refer [clear](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#clear%28%29).
For that you would need to get hold of the current session, which you do in two ways:

1. Get hold of `sessionFactory`, get current session and clear the same.
   `grailsApplication.mainContext.sessionFactory.currentSession.clear()`
2. Use `withSession` closure.

   `DomainABC.withSession{s-> s.clear()}`

Comment: I have at least several hundreds of objects that I load using a HQL and do not want to iteracte and run refresh() individually on each object. There should be someway for purge all the objects from the hibernate session/cache.

Comment: @user593644 See update to the answer. You can use `clear` to clear the session.

Comment: refresh() and session.clear() did not work for me. I tried running native queries to get the data, which I think performed better than HQL queries in getting the data directly from database. But, even that failed over 25% of the times. I then added a `session.flush();` `session.clear();` and `Thread.sleep(2000);` before the fetching the data. Now, it seems to be working fine though I am clueless about why it is so? I don't expect groovy.sql.Sql.execute() to be asychronous. I am puzzled.